# Magento 2: Create Dynamic Category Dropdowns on Frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, ajax, jquery, dropdown-options

I, once again, have to ask for your help. I need to create a modal that let the customer select their car brand, model and year, and I need to populate the select options depending on the selections of the customer. Then, when the customer clicks on 'Save', I have to save the last category ID on a cookie, so I can use it later. I have made some tests but none of them has worked so far. Can you please help me?

My code:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/configCar.html

```
<div id="modal-content">
    <?php
    $parentCategory = $block->getMainCategory();
    ?>
    <div class="field llantas_marca required">
        <label class="label" for="llantas_marca"><span><?php echo __('Seleccione su marca') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <?php
            foreach ($parentCategory as $parent) {
                if ($parent->hasChildren()) {
                    $parentObj = $block->getCategoryById($parent->getId());
                    ?>
                    <select name="llantas_marca" id="llantas_marca" title="<?php echo __('Seleccione su marca') ?>" class="input-text"
                            data-validate="{required:true}">
                        <option value=""><?php echo __('Seleccione una marca') ?></option>
                        <?php
                        $childCategories = $parentObj->getChildrenCategories();
                        foreach ($childCategories as $child):
                            $childObj = $block->getCategoryById($child->getId());
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $child->getId() ?>"><?php echo $childObj->getName() ?></option>
                        <?php
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field llantas_modelo required">
        <label class="label" for="llantas_modelo"><span><?php echo __('Seleccione un modelo') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="llantas_modelo" id="llantas_modelo" title="<?php echo __('Seleccione un modelo') ?>" class="input-text"
                    data-validate="{required:true}">
                <option value=""><?php echo __('Seleccione un modelo') ?></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field llantas_ano required">
        <label class="label" for="llantas_ano"><span><?php echo __('Seleccione un año') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="llantas_modelo" id="llantas_ano" title="<?php echo __('Seleccione un año') ?>" class="input-text"
                    data-validate="{required:true}">
                <option value=""><?php echo __('Seleccione un año') ?></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="configcar-modal-button" data-mage-init='{"configCar": {"target": "#modal-content"}}'>
    Configurador de Coche
</button>
<script>
    jQuery(document).on('change', '#llantas_marca', function () {
        var param = 'frame=' + jQuery('#llantas_marca').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            showLoader: true,
            url: '<?php echo $block->getframeAction(); ?>',
            data: param,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            jQuery('#llantas_modelo').empty();
            jQuery('#llantas_modelo').append(data.value);
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).on('change', '#llantas_modelo', function () {
        var param = 'frame=' + jQuery('#llantas_modelo').val();
        jQuery.ajax({
            showLoader: true,
            url: '<?php echo $block->getframeAction(); ?>',
            data: param,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function (data) {
            jQuery('#llantas_ano').empty();
            jQuery('#llantas_ano').append(data.value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/ConfigCar.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class ConfigCar extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_isScopePrivate;
    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_category;
    protected $_categoryHelper;
    protected $_categoryRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_categoryHelper = $categoryHelper;
        $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    public function getframeAction()
    {
        $url = $this->getUrl('configcar/ajax-handler', ['_secure' => true]);
        return $url;
    }

    public function getMainCategory()
    {
        $this->_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name', 'Por Vehículo')
            ->setPageSize(1);
        return $this->_category;
    }

    public function getCategoryById($categoryId)
    {
        return $this->_categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    }
}
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/ajax-handler.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller;

class Frame extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultJsonFactory;

    protected $regionColFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context            $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Directory\Model\RegionFactory           $regionColFactory)
    {
        $this->regionColFactory = $regionColFactory;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();

        $html = '<option selected="selected" value="">Seleccione una opción</option>';

        $frameName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('frame');
        if ($frameName != '') {
            switch ($frameName) {
                case '6858' :
                    $html .= '<option value="Option 1">Opción 1</option>';
                    $html .= '<option value="Option 2">Opción 2</option>';
                    break;

                default :
                    $html .= '<option value="Option 1">Opción 1</option>';
                    break;

            }
        }

        return $result->setData(['success' => true, 'value' => $html]);
    }
}
```

I think part of my problem resides in that I don't know what exact URL I have to pass to Ajax, and so the petition doesn't get done right. I apreciate all the help I could get

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go over the basics of creating a controller in Magento 2 first https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/create-a-new-page/.

A route in Magento 2 is composed by 3 components: **frontName**/**controllerName**/**actionName**.

The first part, the **frontName**, comes from your declaration in `etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="configcar" frontName="configcar">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Which in this case will be "configcar". (Don't forget to update `module name="Vendor_Module"`).

Next, inside the `Vendor/Module/Controller` you have to create a new folder. The name of this folder will correspond to the **controllerName** part of the route.

Lastly, inside this folder, you create a PHP class, which corresponds to the **actionName**.

So, as an example, your controller could look like `app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/AjaxHandler/Index.php`

And inside the controller class, you would have to update the namespace: `Vendor\Module\Controller\AjaxHandler`

For some reason, in your example, your actual class is named "Frame". Update that to be the same as the file name of the class, in this example: `class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`

So, having all this in place, you should have now the `/configcar/ajaxhandler/index` path available on the front end.

Hint: If your **actionName** is "index", you can skip it, so `/configcar/ajaxhandler/index` is the same as `/configcar/ajaxhandler`. If your **controllerName** were also "index", you could have skipped that one as well. You can check that for example on the checkout page, you can go to it by either typing `/checkout/index/index`, `/checkout/index` or just simply `/checkout`.

P.S. After you figure this out, try to refactor your controller to use [Composition over inheritance](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/extension-coding/common-programming-bp.html#composition-over-inheritance), and instead of extending `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action`, implement `\Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface`.

Comment: Now I understand perfectly how this works and all works as intended. Thank you so much for the answer!